# Java - Iterate Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
Iterator<Player> iterator = plugin.inreview.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Player key = (Player) iterator.next();
    chat.getRecipients().remove(key);
}
```

This throws an: java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? When this occurs, there is one key (with one value) in the map.

Comment: What's the relationship between `chat.getRecipients` and `plugin.inreview`?

Comment: @JonSkeet

There is no relation. This is for Minecraft. `chat.getRecipients` returns the list of players that will be messaged... `this.plugin.inreview` is a Hashmap with a key and a value.

Comment: if you comment out `chat.getRecipients().remove(key);`just for test and run it do you still get this error. I think there is a relationship and you are removing elements from same collection while iterating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your `getRecipients()` returns the same collection as `plugin.inreview`!

This would mean that you try to remove an element from the collection while you are iterating over it. This is of course bad.

Instead, you should do this

```
Vector toRemove=new Vector();
Iterator<Player> iterator = plugin.inreview.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  Player key = (Player) iterator.next();
  toRemove.add(key);
}
chat.getRecipients().removeAll(toRemove);
```

Another possibility is that you have several threads?

Comment: I agree, but prefer LinkedList to Vector.  No good reason for my preference though.

Comment: `getRecipients()` is different from `plugin.inreview`.

Comment: The irony is that this identical bit of code is used in another .Java file and works perfectly fine. Both are setup the same way...

Answer (score 2):

Better solution for iterating a hashmap (java 8+):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
// ...
// ...

map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);
})
```